# Pushing 4K 60Hz via AMD R9 280X?

Tags: windows-7, 4k-resolution, amd-graphics-card

I'm trying to get my PC to output at 4K 60Hz but I can only get 4K at 30HZ. 1080p is the highest that I can output at 60Hz. Here is connection

Sapphire R9 280X > Outputs to: Display Port 1.2 DP-to-HDMI 2.0 converter > Outputs to: HDMI 2.0 Cable to TV

I've tested the TV with another device via the same HDMI cable and achieved 4K and 60Hz (laptop with an Nvidia gpu).

AMD is reporting the following:

[image: AMD TV MAX SETTINGS]

But Windows is only displaying:

[image: Windows Resolution Options]

Shouldn't I be able to push 4K @ 60Hz through the DP-to-HDMI 2.0 converter method?

Comment: Could you name the exact model of your card? As per the [AMD site](http://www.amd.com/en-en/products/graphics/desktop/r9) (Footnotes) it could be that your card simply doesn't support more.

Comment: I think you need at least DP1.3 to get 60Hz at UHD

Comment: @Seth The page doesn't work for me but [this](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814202088) is the card that I had purchased

Comment: @magicandre1981 It is possible but the internet seems to be anything but clear about this..

Comment: @magicandre1981 DP1.2 Supports 4K at 60Hz (You can even push it to about 75Hz), so I do not believe this is the problem.

Comment: There are various reports for that card in regards to 4k and 60 Hz. What adapter are you using? It might not support 60 Hz? Doesn't look like Sapphire puts their manuals online. You probably should check yours for supported resolutions and frequencies. About the [link](http://www.amd.com/de-de/products/graphics/desktop/r9)... sorry but looks like there is only a German version available?

Comment: ok, I don't use DP or UHD display. thanks for the information :)